# Handling special cases in SQL connection string Python

Tags: python, sql, connection-string, sqlconnection

Currently this is how I am creating a SQL connection string.

```
def connect_DB():



    admin_connection_info = {
        "user" : "USER" ,
        "password" :"qihvnw@zwA@8" ,
        "service" : "abcdmcewbv.com",
        "port" :"10000" ,
        "host" : "localhost"
    }
    
    admin_connection_string = '{user}/{password}@{host}:{port}/{service}'.format(**admin_connection_info) # constructing connection string 
  
    print("DB Connection String, ADMIN  " + str(admin_connection_string))

    return admin_connection_string
```

I face issues when my password contains special characters like @ at any position

Case 1 Details:

username: USER

pwd: qihvnw@zwA@8

host: localhost

port: 10000

ServiceName: abcdmcewbv.com

'@' issue connection string shown below:

> USER/qihvnw@zwA@8@localhost:10000/abcdmcewbv.com

once it encounters the first '@', it assumes everything after that till the first ':' is host name.
here it probably assumes,

pwd: qihvnw

host: zwA@8@localhost

This is wrong.

Case 2 Details:

username: USER//

pwd: qihvnw@zwA@8

host: localhost

port: 10000

ServiceName: abcdmcewbv.com

'//' issue in username connection string below

> USER///qihvnw@zwA@8@localhost:10000/abcdmcewbv.com

Here even though username is USER//

It assumes everything after the first '/' to be part of the password, i.e

correct password -> qihvnw@zwA@8

wrong password -> //qihvnw (Case 1 issue carries over here)

How do I resolve such a case.
This is only a sample of what the password could look like and these are from ADMIN,  I cannot ask them to not use such special characters.

Please suggest a workaround to build a valid connection string.
The above mentioned parameters are compulsory (uname,pwd,host,port,servicename)

If there is an alternate more robust method of building connection strings that can handle such edge cases please do let me know

Comment: This isn't a string issue. The connection string uses a URL format. You need to URL-encode anything that may contain characters that are special in a URL

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos , would appreciate if you could ellaborate with an example.

Comment: Did you check the duplicate? It answers the exact same question you have and shows how to use the `urlquote` method. Have you tried using eg `urlquote("qihvnw@zwA@8")`?

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos yes Issue resolved